# D3 - redraw SVG after DOM change

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm struggling with redrawing/updating my SVG.  I included the enter-update-exit method for my data and my DOM structure looks like the following:

```
<svg>
  <g id="groupOfRectangles">
    <rect>
    <rect>
    <rect>
    <rect>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now I want to group some specific rectangles together in my DOM structure. For example:

```
<svg>
  <g id="groupOfRectangles">
    <rect>  
    <g id="Group1">
      <rect>
      <rect>  
    </g>  
    <rect>
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here I have got so far:

```
var rect = render();  
//until here, everything is displayed correctly
d3.select(rect._groups[0][x]).before('g').attr("id", "Group" + 1);
document.getElementById("Group1").appendChild(rect._groups[0][x]);
document.getElementById("Group1").appendChild(rect._groups[0][x]);  
render();
```

After doing this the rectangles, which are grouped by "Group1" are hidden in my visualisation, but still grouped right in my DOM tree. So I have tried to recall my render function, but nothing changes.

```
function render() {
    var group = rectGroup.selectAll("rect").data(nodes);

    group = group.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.value; })
            .attr("height", rectHeight)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

    group.select("rect")
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.value; })
            .attr("height", rectHeight)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

    group.exit().remove();

    return group;
}
```

The reason of doing this, is for the interaction with the rectangles, I want to implement later. That I only have to interact with one group of rectangles, instead of looking for every single rect, which belongs together. So what I'm doing wrong? Is there any more effective method to group specific rectangles?

Or is it possible (perhaps easier?) to group them together before I call the render function?

**EDIT-1:**
Here is some working code where I'm switching 2 rectangle elements to a new group in the DOM tree. You can see it in the second line of the schedule function.

```
var width = 500;
var height = 500;

obj1 = {value: 99, x: 0, y:25, height: 20};
obj2 = {value: 200, x: 0, y:50, height: 20};
obj3 = {value: 300, x: 0, y:100, height: 20};
obj4 = {value: 250, x: 0, y:125, height: 20};
obj5 = {value: 370, x: 0, y:75, height: 20};
var myData = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

var rectGroup = svg.append("g").attr("id", "groupOfRectangles");

d3.selection.prototype.before = function(tagName) {
    var elements = [];

    this.each(function() {
        var element = document.createElement(tagName);
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(element, this);
        elements.push(element);
    });

    return d3.selectAll(elements);
};

function render() {
    var group = rectGroup.selectAll("rect").data(myData);

    group = group.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.value; })
            .attr("height", rectHeight)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

    group.select("rect")
            .attr("width", function(d) { return d.value; })
            .attr("height", rectHeight)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

    group.exit().remove();

    return group;
}

function schedule() {
    var rect = render();
    d3.select(rect._groups[0][3]).before('g').attr("id", "Group" + 1);
    document.getElementById("Group1").appendChild(rect._groups[0][3]);
    document.getElementById("Group1").appendChild(rect._groups[0][4]);
}

schedule();
```

Comment: How do you add `<g id="Group1">` to the DOM?  Can you provide some working/runnable code?

Comment: @Mark the second line of the schedule function adds the Group1 to the DOM. I have added some runnable example code.

Comment: If I'm just using the pure DOM API to append a new group element and new childs for it, I'm getting the same results, the DOM tree works correct but the visualisation svg not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `before` prototype, you need to use `createElementNS` and specify the `SVG` namespace:

```
this.each(function() {
  var element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tagName);
  this.parentNode.insertBefore(element, this);
  elements.push(element);
});
```